# how java manage jdbc connections

Tags: jdbc, tomcat7, spring-aop

I have an spring advice method which logs the exception after a method (in DAO layer) throws an exception. The DB query are handled at DAO classes.

while running the code my service method (S1), which interns call DAO layer method (D1) to execute query.

test case: DB is up and code execute normally. in second run, meanwhile DB is down, and calls doesn't reach to DAO layer and exception throws (Connect excpetion) at service layer (S1) itself; hence advise not able to log the excpetion because calls is not reached to DAO.

how the jdbc connections are managed by server (tomcat)?

Comment: Generally jdbc work as expected, Can you  share with as  log exception and snippet of your code, so we can reproduce your case

Comment: FYI here is a link explaining how to write questions on SO (or on any technical forum or mailing list) as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get meaningful answers. Otherwise you will probably get close votes instead. You already have two, BTW.